# Member reference base type 'double' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and can't figure out how to fix the error, would greatly appreciate for your help
The part where the error occurs I'm trying to input the radius into the `cirArea[]` array, but it does not seem to work.

Here's a part of my code:

```
int main(){
    Circle *area;
    double cirRadius;
    int numCircle;

    cout << "How many circles?" << endl;
    cin >> numCircle;
    double cirArea[numCircle];

    for (int i = 0; i < numCircle; i++){
        cout << "Enter the radius: ";
        cin >> cirRadius;
        cirArea[i].setRadius(cirRadius);
    }
}
```

For setRadius():

```
void Circle::setRadius(double r){
    if (r >= 0)
        radius = r;
    else {
        cout << "Invalid radius\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

so here's the ERROR:

```
member reference base type 'double' is not a structure or union
            cirArea[i].setRadius(cirRadius);
            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an statically allocated array with 'not a constant size'.
Second issue is that `cirArea` is not of `Circle` type but of `double`.

You would have to allocate it dynamically (and delete it afterwards) and make it `Circle` type:

```
int main(){
    double cirRadius;
    int numCircle;

    cout << "How many circles?" << endl;
    cin >> numCircle;
    Circle *area = new Circle[numCircle];

    for (int i = 0; i < numCircle; i++){
        cout << "Enter the radius: ";
        cin >> cirRadius;
        cirArea[i].setRadius(cirRadius);
    }

    delete[] area;
}
```

But a preferable way of doing it would be to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

struct Circle
{
    double radius;

    void setRadius(double r){
        if (r >= 0)
            radius = r;
        else {
            std::cout << "Invalid radius\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }    
}   ; 

int main(){
    double cirRadius;
    int numCircle;

    std::cout << "How many circles?\n";
    std::cin >> numCircle;
    std::vector<Circle> area;
    area.reserve(numCircle);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCircle; ++i){
        std::cout << "Enter the radius: ";
        std::cin >> cirRadius;
        area.emplace_back();
        area.back().setRadius(cirRadius);
    }

    for( Circle& i : area )
    {
      std::cout << i.radius << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://cpp.sh/3l7ti

Comment: Since it is C++ tagged I would go with std::vector rather than dynamic arrays

Comment: I know :) I was just editing this answer but I couldn't do it any faster. Please check my edits - that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cirArea` has a type double, not `Circle`, so you cant't apply on it `Circle` method.
Change the type of `cirArea` from `double` to `Circule` to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially this statement that's at fault:

`double cirArea[numCircle];`

Variable length arrays are not supported in C++, and I think you mean to use a `Circle` object as the element rather than a `double`.

Use a `std::vector<Circle>` instead to model a vectors of `Circle` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cirArea` is an array of `double` and not of `Circle`. The `double` type does of course not have `Circle` member functions (or any member functions at all).

Since your compiler seems to support [variable-lenght arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) I suppose you really want

```
Circle cirArea[numCircle];
```

---

Variable-length arrays are not a standard C++ feature, if you want to make the program portable you should use `std::vector` like

```
std::vector<Circle> cirArea(numCircle);
```

Answer (score 0):

`double cirArea[numCircle];` is an `array` of `double`. It should be an `array` of `Circle`. However, `numCircle` is a non-const so you can not do that (even if the compiler allow it. It is not standared). You should use `dynamically allocated array` or even better a `std::vector`.

A complete C++ solution would be :

```
int main(){
    Circle *area;
    double cirRadius;
    int numCircle;

    cout << "How many circles?" << endl;
    cin >> numCircle;
    std::vector<Circle> cirArea;
    cirArea.reserve(numCircle);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCircle; i++){
        cout << "Enter the radius: ";
        cin >> cirRadius;
        cirArea.emplace_back(); 
        cirArea.back().setRadius(cirRadius);
    }
}
```

if `Circle` accept `Radius` as `constructor argument`, you may replace those two lines:

```
cirArea.emplace_back(); 
cirArea.back().setRadius(cirRadius);
```

with:

```
cirArea.emplace_back(cirRadius);
```